# Creating a datatable in JavaFx

Tags: java, charts, datatable, javafx

i want to create a table that is connected with my chart the idea is that it display the information on the chart in details.

here is a picture i found to give you an idea of how it should be builded (however i want the graph to be made in JavaFx and therefore the graph and table it self should be more smooth and with better graphics):

[image]

As you can see on the picture the information under for day (D1,D2,D3) is displayed right under the bars. how would i create a similar thing in JavaFx?